2024 Kia Sportage Hybrid SX-Prestige makes a loud noise when accelerating
It's a new SUV, and I've noticed that loud gear-like noise when accelerating from 20 to 30 mph. I'm concerned about this. Could it be related to switching gears? Is it normal? Should I take it to the dealer for a check-up?

Since the car is new, I would absolutely take it back to the dealer to have them look at it.  That's what a new car warranty is for.
If there's a problem, they'll fix it.  If it's a normal noise, they will explain what it is.  Also, there's a record of you bringing the car for service in case the problem gets worse.
